# What should we enter in APPLICATION_NAME and APPLICATION_VERSION fields in Amazon MWS PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I don't know what should I enter in below fields in amazon [MWS PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/amazon-mws-php-fork/source/browse/trunk/src/MarketplaceWebService/Samples/.config.inc.php?r=5)

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', '<Your Application Name>');  
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', '<Your Application Version or Build Number>');
```

If anyone know about Application name and version in Amazon MWS, explain about application name and version.

Comment: Your application name and version?

Comment: @vanneto I am developing a system to export my store products to seller central. So I used MWS PHP library. I don't know what should I enter into APPLICATION_NAME, APPLICATION_VERSION fields.

Comment: My custom samples run without an application name and version. The samples are garbage.

Answer (score 9):

You enter the application name and version. According to a comment in the file you linked to:

```
/*
* All MWS requests must contain a User-Agent header. The application
* name and version defined below are used in creating this value.
*/
```

So, the application name and version are used to create the user agent string. You said your application will be used to export your store products to seller central. So use a name like `MyProductExporter` and the version will be `1.0` and then when you upgrade it you can set the version to `1.1`.

So, for example, mine would look something like:

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'MyAWESOMEProductExporter');  
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', '1.1.391');
```

So it's for identifying your client via `User-Agent` - as long as it's unique, put whatever makes sense to you in there.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Now understood about app name & version. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'MarketplaceWebServiceProducts PHP5 Library');
define('APPLICATION_VERSION', '2');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tejesh002/amazon-mws

**php composer package for settlement**

- GetReportList
- GetReportRequest
- GetReport
- UpdateAcknowledge